# How to disable the drawing cache?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm using a ListView to show plenty of images (endless scrolling). When I start to scroll down the list this messages floods the logcat:

> WARN/View(15722): View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 1639680 bytes, only 1536000 available

I'm having trouble to understand the drawing cache mechanism but it seems to be enabled by default as I did not enable it. I assume it would be better to disable it because it produces hundreds of warnings within seconds. But I've got no idea which view is actually causing this issue. I tried to apply `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)` to all involved views but the issue remained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Applying `setScrollingCacheEnabled( false )` to the ListView did the trick.